# How to monitor traffic statistics on my wireless modem router?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, network-traffic

How can I monitor the network traffic statistics for all connected computers to my wireless modem router?
Something like what [Network Meter](http://addgadgets.com/network_meter) does for a single PC.

**EDIT:**
My modem router is: `TP-LINK TD-W8951ND`.

Comment: What `wireless modem router` do you have?

Comment: @David Is that relevant? TP-LINK TD-W8951ND.

Comment: Yes, different devices have different capabilities.

Comment: @David Added to the question then.

Comment: Only the Version 5 manual is online: http://www.tp-link.com/resources/document/TD-W8951ND_V5_User_Guide_1910010890.pdf

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the version 5 manual, I would say you can only collect aggregate (total) information on how much information the router is transmitting (TX) and receiving (RX), and that you can not collect information for individual hosts on the network.

In the manual, please consult:
Section 4.1.3 Statistics
Page 18/19

If you wish to monitor individual host bandwidth utilisation, you will require a more advanced setup, probably involving a linux or BSD system, or a more advance router from Cisco or Juniper.  You could reuse an old computer, or purchase more specialised hardware.

You could try loading dd-wrt or open-wrt firmware on to your router, but you will likely have trouble because the ADSL drivers are not that complete, so this is fraught with dangers.  It would be very easy to brick your router going this way if you do not know what you are doing.